# AngularJS: $scope says variable is undefined when using $resource

Tags: angularjs

The console.log is saying that a variable is undefined, but my two other `console.log`s are saying otherwise:

I have a controller:

```
app.controller('ProductDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$resource', 'Product', function($scope, $resource, Product) {
  $scope.init = function(id)
  {
    $scope.product = Product.get({productId: id});
  }

  $scope.$watch('product', function() {
    console.log($scope.product); //<-- prints out a resource with products_colors
    $scope.selected_color = $scope.product.products_colors[0];
  });

  // $scope.selected_color = $scope.product.products_colors[0];

}]);
```

a factory:

```
app.factory('Product', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  return $resource("/api/products/:productId", {}, {
    query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true},
  });
}]);
```

And a view:

```
<div ng-controller="ProductDetailCtrl" ng-init="init(<%= @product.id %>)">


    <select ng-model="selected_color" ng-options="product_color as product_color.color.name for product_color in product.products_colors"></select>
    {{ product.products_colors[0] }} <!-- {"id":31,"color_id":4,"product_id":30,"mens":true,"womens":true,"created_at":"2014-05-27T20:26:03.000Z","updated_at" ... } -->


</div>
```

However, the console in my browser says this:

```
Error: $scope.product.products_colors is undefined @http://localhost:3000/assets/products/controllers/productscontroller.js?body=1:9:5 $RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:12448:23 $RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:12713:13 bootstrap/doBootstrap/<@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:1420:9 invoke@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:3919:7 bootstrap/doBootstrap@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:1419:1 bootstrap@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:1432:5 angularInit@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:1345:5 @http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:21818:5 jQuery.Callbacks/fire@http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.js?body=1:3100:1 jQuery.Callbacks/self.fireWith@http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.js?body=1:3212:7 .ready@http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.js?body=1:3424:3 completed@http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.js?body=1:3454:3


return logFn.apply(console, args);
```

What's going on? Does this have to do with my factory and use of $resource? Because when I hardcode it the JSON response instead of using `Product.get(..)`, it works perfectly fine as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/HB7LU/ . I double checked that my API works by going to `http://localhost:3000/api/products/30` directly

== UPDATE ==

I tried what @lucuma and @Darren suggested but it didn't work:

```
app.controller('ProductDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$resource', 'Product', function($scope, $resource, Product) {
  $scope.product = {};

  $scope.init = function(id)
  {
    $scope.product = Product.get({productId: id});
  }

  $scope.$watch('product', function(newVal) {
    if (angular.isUndefined(newVal)) {
      return;  
    }  


    console.log($scope.product);
    $scope.selected_color = $scope.product.products_colors[0];
  });

  // $scope.selected_color = $scope.product.products_colors[0];

}]);
```

The colors are all loaded onto the select, but there is still an error and the default option is still empty

Answer (score 0):

Because the watch is evaluating before your Resource returns it is throwing an error.  You can make this change it will probably work:

```
$scope.$watch('product', function(newVal) {
  if (angular.isUndefined(newVal))  <--  add this line to check if undefined -->
    return;  

  console.log($scope.product); //<-- prints out a resource with products_colors
  $scope.selected_color = $scope.product.products_colors[0];

});
```

Comment: Hey Lucuma I updated my question with your suggestion but it didn't work

Comment: Change the if condition to angular.isUndefined(newVal) || angular.isUndefined(newVal.products)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your product service is wired up though likely that your view is ready well before $scope.product gets applied.

So try setting $scope.product = {}; on the first line of your controller to properly set an existence of the object.

Comment: Hey Darren I tried it but it didn't work. I updated my questino

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with your factory is that you are instantiating the page before the objects come back from the Api. Thus you need a promise to resolve the data back from the Api. An example for this would be

```
 $scope.init = function(id)
  {
    var thisProduct = Product.get({productId: id});
    thisProduct.$promise.then(function(data){
       $scope.produce = data;
    }
  }
```

Hope that helps,

Patrick